# Multiple related samples in Regression with few participants

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, repeated-measures

I want to run a regression on a dataset with very few participants but with multiple related observations.

How I may form random effects? i must declare them for every instance of them?

I found also that, is of any help?: "[post][1]"

e.g. 
summary(lme( Run ~ wellness* id + fit * id + happiness * id, data=df, random= ~1| id))  ?

1. id is the participants
2. within indicate the repeated measures of
   variables Example df:

   ```
   df<-
       structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
       2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
       5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), within = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
       1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
       5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
       "5", "6"), class = "factor"), IQ = c(977, 79, 
       83, 753, 951, NA, 1127, 415, 285, 2, 54, 
       NA, 4, 4, 59, 854, 511, NA, 1413, 138, 1262, 
       114, 832, NA, 946, 146, 117, 883, 749, NA), 
           Run = c(17, 711, 65, 543, 839, NA, 843, 424, 
           149, 1, 414, NA, 4, 55, 423, 614, 434, NA, 941, 115, 
           954, 616, 74, NA, 843, 947, 739, 74, 529, NA), wellness = c(387, 
           431, 25, 21, 13, 194, 331, 1, 419, 316, 
           244, 12, 2, 24, 246, 243, 917, 252, 276, 
           269, 22, 147, 1, 16, 282, 45, 222, 273, 
           252, 11), happiness = c(391, 473, 384, 41, 462, 378, 
           275, 2, 3, 261, 349, 326, 286, 3, 2, 264, 
           2, 1, 3, 445, 485, 312, 2, 42, 353, 366, 
           224, 2, 2, 2)), .Names = c("id", "within", "Run", 
       "wellness", "fit", "happiness"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
   ```

   [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131977/repeated-measure-anova-using-regression-models-lm-lmer

Comment: Why does everything interact with id? Is your idea is: Run can be predicted from wellness, fit and happiness?

Comment: Yes exactly - so i have written that in the right manner? However, I would like to know if the sample size is also enough to perform that regression. I have 5 participants measured 5 times. therefore, 5*5=25 observations. Are these observations enough to include how many variables in the Regression equation? 1 or 2 or 3?

Comment: 5 participants measured 5 times. Is the interval between measurements the same for everyone?

Comment: yes! the interval of measuremtn is the same across all participants and across all type of measurements e.g. 1 day interval

Comment: 6 times (6 days  experiment - sorry for the error)

Comment: You're on the low end. McNeish and Stapleton show that for such cluster sizes - 5, mixed effects models are not optimal. It is better to run a fixed effect model and multiply by something called the DEFT. This is their paper - http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2016.1167008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could analyze your data. If you want to account for clustering, McNeish and Stapleton (2016) advice that you run it as a fixed-effect model given your small cluster size. They then advice that you adjust the standard errors by multiplying them by the DEFT, and retesting your regression coefficients for statistical significance.

First, I would advice that you take care of missing data; Yang and Peng (2013) would be a useful starting point.

I would start by plotting the outcome $(run)$ over time. Is it linear, quadratic, ...? You have six time points, theoretically, you could test all the way to quintic. It's wise to stop at quartic (4, $n(time)-2$).

I'm going to assume $run$ is linear over time. You could then perform a simple linear regression.

```
df$id <- factor(df$id)
model.lm <- lm(run ~ time + wellness + fit + happiness + id, data = df)
summary(model.lm)
```

If nothing is statistically significant at this point, I would not bother progressing along this line because the next step is to inflate the standard errors.

We can calculate the DEFT using the `nlme` package, which I assume you already have:

```
model.lme <- lme(run ~ 1, data = df, random = ~1|id)
var <- as.numeric(VarCorr(model.lme)[, 1])
icc <- var[1] / sum(var)
deff <- 1 + icc * (6 - 1) # 6 is the number of time points per id
deft <- sqrt(deff)

# Final stage: use DEFT to increase standard errors
model.lm <- summary(model.lm)
model.lm.se <- as.numeric(model.lm$coefficients[, 2]) # Obtain standard errors
model.lm.se <- model.lm.se * deft # Multiply them by DEFT
# Obtain coefficient of se for creating confidence intervals
t <- qt(.975, model.lm$df[2])
lower.bound <- model.lm$coefficients[, 1] - t * model.lm.se
upper.bound <- model.lm$coefficients[, 1] + t * model.lm.se
(final.results <- data.frame(
  estimate = as.numeric(model.lm$coefficients[, 1]),
  se <- model.lm.se, lb <- lower.bound, up <- upper.bound
))
```

`final.results` now contains your modeling results. You can see the estimates for the different predictors and their 95% confidence intervals. I believe this is an implementation of McNeish and Stapleton's recommendation.

---

McNeish, D., & Stapleton, L. M. (2016). Modeling Clustered Data with Very Few Clusters. *Multivariate Behavioral Research, 51*(4), 495–518. https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2016.1167008

Dong, Y., & Peng, C.-Y. J. (2013). Principled missing data methods for researchers. *SpringerPlus, 2*(1), 222. https://doi.org/10.1186/2193-1801-2-222